# global variable in all symfony2 app

Tags: symfony, global-variables

I am working in my project for the university with symfony2, and I have a problem since two days ago which I have not idea how to resolve.

I need a global variable shared between various users (various user sessions) but I don't know where I have to declare it.

I would like when user A change this variable then user B can read this variable updated.

Likely it is not possible but I am new in symfon2 and I am not sure.

Sorry if I have any mistake in the redaction but I am learning English now :)

Answer (score 1):

You can write that variable to file or cache (apc-cache, for example). Cache will be shared between all requests, however,  it has lifetime.

Comment: +1 - I was just about to suggest using Redis, but apc-cache would be just as good for this.

Comment: Ok, thanks Son!I though write that variable in a .json file and put it in app/Resources folder, Would be correct this location?. I will see something about apc-cache I think could be interesting.

Comment: You can store anywhere you want, but I think you should create your own folder in app, the Resources folder is where I store resource files like twig, css, js.. for the Bundles. If you store in file, you may have some problems with concurrent read/write. If you need to write into it many times, I think you should consider storing it in database.

Comment: Finally I`ve decided to use a .json file and ensure mutex with the php's semaphores implementation and function flock (for windows systems), as we can see in one user contribution in the php manual in this link [Semaphpres in php and Class Mutex](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.sem.php). Thanks a lot for the help! Son.